# App Engine - Subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain

I have deployed an application on Google App Engine and I want to link a Subdomian to that application.
I currently have a domain that is linked to a "live" site. from Google documentation I understand that i need to set up my domain with Google Apps:

> To serve your app on a custom domain, the domain must be set up with Google Apps
>   ([Source](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html))

What exactly that mean? 
I've looked in Google documentation and could get a clear idea...
Does that will effected my "live" site in some way?

just to clarify, **www.mydomain.com** - points a site that i own and i want **sub.mydomain.com** to point to my Google application.

Comment: Just follow the steps in the document you linked to - what are you confused about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to make a `CNAME` to forward to your app address.
Let's say your app address is `https://yourapp.appspot.com`, and you want `sub.mydomain.com` to forward to it, just do like below:

Please read [**THIS**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html) first, follow the steps until step 5. You'll need to type your `mydomain.com` in step 3, and type `sub` in step 5. After these, you'll some steps on how to **Chang CNAME record**, just follow:

1. set your host name to `sub`
2. Type: `CNAME`
3. IP address/host name: `ghs.google.com.`
4. Priority status: (whatever just make it's the number)

OK, and you'll visit your app by **http://sub.mydomain.com**, different hosting providers have different time to set it valid. :)

BTW, it'll not effect your "live" site in any way. As your main site use `mydomain.com`, and you just need `sub.mydomain.com`. What GAE said is that, if you want to set `mydomain.com` to your app, you need to set `A` type instead of `CNAME` type in your host. This domain hosting method includes more steps, you'll see GAE's doc that you found, and so it **will effect your live site**.

Comment: The CNAME needs to point to `ghs.google.com`, not `yourapp.appspot.com`.

Comment: I don't understand, so to redirect to custom url, i need google business apps, which isn't free? Just for redirect?

Comment: @Jack why google business apps? u don't need it. You just need the app on the GAE and a domain name (which u can get from any domain name site), then set the subdomain correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This means you have to register your domain with Google Apps here: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new

You don't have to have your main website hosted on Google. Just how you arrange things is determined by how you configure your DNS which you will retain control of. Same for email you can have it delivered to Google Apps or not, depending on your DNS MX records.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your ownership using webmasters by adding a txt record in you dns records, after that it will appears in the list of domains under App Engine > Settings > Custom domains.